# Passing Local Variable in Rails 5 Best Practice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to dry up my code and decided to use a partial for my page title and pass a local variable into it.  It works, but I want to know if I am conforming to the Rails best practice.

**partials/_page-header.html.erb**

```
<section class="hero is-primary">
  <div class="hero-body">
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="title">
        <%= title %>
      </h1>
      <h2 class="subtitle">
        Hero subtitle
      </h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

**static_pages/home.html.erb**
I would add this to the top of all my views

```
<% provide(:title, 'Home') %>
...
```

**application.html.rb**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <%= render 'partials/head' %>
  <%= render 'partials/head-scripts' %>
  <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>
</head>
<body>
<%= render 'partials/nav' %>
<%= render 'partials/page-header', title: yield(:title) %>
<section class="section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content">
      <%= yield %>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<%= render 'partials/footer' %>
<%= render 'partials/footer-scripts' %>
</body>
</html>
```